# Anylogic-how to create parament containing changing growth rate over time

Tags: anylogic

I am building a simulation in Anylogic. I am new to anylogic. I would like to define a parameter: e.g. expected growth rate. it is not constant. it changes monthly.  I would like to assign growth rate over a 18 month horizon and add product variants. e,g. product A, growthrate is 5% in the first month, Product B is 4% in the first month. product A, growthrate is 3% in the second month, Product B is 5% in the second month.

How do I realize the requirement in Anylogic

Bests
Zishi

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions on *fixing a specific problem*, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is a generic “how do I best do X” question. This is too broad for SOF and better asked in a forum like LinkedIn. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help on specifics :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called `growthRates` of type `ArrayList<Double>()` of size how many products you simulate.

Create an integer variable called `month`.

Create a `Source` block that creates a dummy agent every month and connect it to a `Sink` block. Inside `Sink` block, `On Enter` section, update your variables based on the time. For example;

```
month+=1;
if (month==0){
   growthRates.set(0, 0.05); //growth rate for product A
   growthRates.set(1, 0.04; //growth rate for product B
}
else if(month==1){

   growthRates.set(0, 0.06); //growth rate for product A
   growthRates.set(1, 0.03); //growth rate for product B
}

...
```

Then in your simulation, you use this variable `growthRates` with the correct index when referring to different products.